# Colorbars appear outside the subplots in Surface subplots with Plotly and all overlapping

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, subplot, colorbar, surface

I would like to see each surface subplot with its own colorbar positioned next to it.  Instead, my code gets all the colorbars of the subplots on the right side of the figure overlapping each other.  It is not clear to me what is wrong with my code. How can I correct it?

Here is the code:

```
def bern(theta, z, N):
    
    """Bernoulli likelihood with N trials and z successes."""
    
    return np.clip(theta**z * (1-theta)**(N-z), 0, 1)

def bern2(theta1, theta2, z1, z2, N1, N2):
    
    """Bernoulli likelihood with N trials and z successes."""
    
    return bern(theta1, z1, N1) * bern(theta2, z2, N2)

def make_thetas(xmin, xmax, n):
    
    xs = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, n)
    
    widths =(xs[1:] - xs[:-1])/2.0
    
    thetas = xs[:-1]+ widths
    
    return thetas

thetas1 = make_thetas(0, 1, 101)

thetas2 = make_thetas(0, 1, 101)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(thetas1, thetas2)

a = 2

b = 3

z1 = 11

N1 = 14

z2 = 7

N2 = 14

prior = stats.beta(a, b).pdf(X) * stats.beta(a, b).pdf(Y)

likelihood = bern2(X, Y, z1, z2, N1, N2)


posterior = stats.beta(a + z1, b + N1 - z1).pdf(X) * stats.beta(a + z2, b + N2 - z2).pdf(Y)

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=3, specs= [[{'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}, {'is_3d': True}]], subplot_titles=('Prior', 'Likelihood', 'Posterior'))

fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= prior,  showscale= True), 1, 1)




fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= likelihood,  showscale= True), 1, 2)




fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= posterior,  showscale= True),1,3, False)

fig.update_layout(title='Prior - Likelihood - Posterior', autosize= True,
                  width= 1300, height=600,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))


fig.show()
```

The output of the code is this:

[image]

Comment: @user870077 Will your code snippet produce the plot you are displaying here?

Comment: This appears to essentially be [the same problem as your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896471/colorbar-is-overlapping-with-contour-plot-in-plotly), with much the same code.

Comment: @vestland This is my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 3 surfaces and all of them are "showscale=True" without given specific position. You can move and even resize them on the plot with

```
colorbar=dict(len=0.5, x=0.8)
```

like this:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Surface(z= likelihood,showscale= True,colorbar=dict(len=0.5, x=0.8)), 1, 2)
```